# ¿Cómo crear un menú en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, menú

Bueno tengo un breve problema, quiero desarrollar un menú dentro de mi aplicación.

Código del Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".InicioApp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_width="400sp">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/Menu1"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Código de mi clase de java

```
public class InicioApp extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.inicio_app);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.inicio_app, menu); --El error esta aqui
        }

    }
```

Me sale un problema que dice "Expected resource of type menu".

Comment: Android Studio te da la opción de crear un menú directamente cuando abres un proyecto nuevo. Si quieres arreglar el error, mira a ver la solución @Orici. Si quieres una solución rápida, usa el que te da Android Studio y modifícalo a tu gusto.

Comment: David, he agregado una respuesta, recuerda que es importante que el método onCreateOptionsMenu() tambien retorne un valor de tipo boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**El error que comentas es porque no reconoce tu recurso como tipo `menu`**, lo que tratas de cargar no es de tipo menu, en realidad es un layout:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.inicio_app, menu); --El error esta aqui
}
```

debes agregar el layout de tipo menu dentro del folder `/menu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.inicio_app, menu);
    return true;
}
```

---

Como ejemplo, tu menu debe tener una estructura similar a:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Revisa la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes definida la id "inicio_app" en el xml, por lo que la clase java no encuentra el menu.
Te faltaría añadir:

> android:id="@+id/inicio_app"